# Get visitors of a specific site Sharepoint Online using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to get a list of all the users who visited a specific SharePoint Online site using the OOTB functionality or Powershell.

The Popularity Usage export is basically doing what I require but it doesn't provide a list of users but just numbers. Does SharePoint store the usernames of the visitors or is it just holding a counter?

Comment: I dont think its possible from Powershell because it does not deal directly like Client side scripting. Its possible with javascript ; may be as in form of an widget like how blogs work . But there is no possibility in powershell with that unless you are bringing some workaround which can call a javascript on the fly(something like that).

Comment: Thanks Ranadip, I thought as much. So a good solution would be to create a widget and capture the traffic from there.

Comment: @Udomi: Yes, I believe so .Do you want me to put that as an answer so that you can close it off?